# javascript - onmouseleave check if mouse is on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code but it's not working.

```
$("#menu-item-875").mouseover(function(){
    $(".dropdownCategories").css("display", "block").fadeIn();
});
$("#menu-item-875").mouseout(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".dropdownCategories").css("display", "none");
    }, 1000);
});
$(".dropdownCategories").mouseover(function(){
    $(".dropdownCategories").css("display", "block");
});
```

You should be able to mouseover `#menu-item-875` and then have time to go to `.dropdownCategories`. Otherwise people cannot click the links in the div. I set a delay on the mouseout, but that has to cancel when someone hovers over the actual div `.dropdownCategories`.

Comment: can you post your `html` too??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout doesn't really matter, the event will execute, because you are not on `$("#menu-item-875")` anymore.

Can't you create a wrapper that includes both `$("#menu-item-875")` and `$(".dropdownCategories")` ? And you will not need the last `$(".dropdownCategories")` and then use the `$("#wrapper_id").mouseout(function(){})`

Comment: Exactly what i needed. With this I don't even need the delay, don't know how I didn't think of this